# Shaders work in unity editor, but not in the build, even after adding shaders to always included list

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a project I'm working on that uses shaders.

It should look something like this: [image]

It looks like this in the editor, anyway.

When I build it, it looks like this: [image]

My guess is the shaders, and when I looked up the problem I found that people had trouble with not adding their shaders to the **always included shaders** list.

- I added the relevant shaders to no avail
- I then added all of the shaders in my assets and packages folders, and nothing changed aside from load time

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. I've not needed to expicity specify things like shaders preferring indead to letting Unity work it out.  **However,** what is important is that when configuring a build you **add the current scene**.  Do you have more than one scene?

Comment: I only have one scene, and it's selected and checked in build settings. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Can you tell us more about the build?  What are you targeting? _Windows? Android?_  What settings are you using on the Build page?

Comment: I'm targeting webGL, but the problems actually persist in the basic windows build too, and based on that probably the others, although I haven't tried them. I'll add a pic of the build settings to the main post.

Comment: I also just tested it in dev mode, and the console is spamming that "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: shader". I have no idea what this is referring to.

Comment: OK, try focusing on a Windows Build first and running on the same computer as Unity. 
 If that works try Web. Thanks for the updates

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still not sure what the problem was, but a changed a problematic shader and the issue resolved itself.